# Search Replace Database ONLY for posts of certain category?

Tags: categories, database, search, limit, customization

I need to search/replace my database but **limit the action to posts of certain categories.**

Is this possible? I usually use https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB, but there is no way to limit by category. I also found this on Stack Overflow, but it didn't work (and I don't understand what it's doing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171025/limiting-search-and-replace-to-category

Any ideas?? Its for a website with around 1000 pages so I can't just do it manually.

Comment: Why the downvote I can't find an answer

Comment: Tell us more about what you want to achieve.